# Output change with find when using print0

Tags: find

When I use find depending where I put the option print0, I get different output, why? And where should I put it?

```
find ./ -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t myfolder 
find ./ -print0 -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.png" | xargs -0 mv -t myfolder
```

Comment: `find` evaluates primaries (each of `-print0`, `-name blah`, etc.) from left to right, if you put `-print0` at the beginning, it prints all files, and if you put it elsewhere, it prints files for which all of the primaries preceding `-print0` evaluates to true. These are all written in the manual though, have you tried reading it?

Comment: It should be put at the beginning? I read the manual but with the "or" i'm confused how the primaries are evaluate...

Comment: Depends on what you want it to print. Like, the first command in your question prints all PNG files (as `-a` is implied between primaries in juxtaposition, and has a higher precedence than `-o`), and the second prints all the files. And this one `find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -print0` prints all JPG and PNG files.

Comment: But, you don't really need `-print0` and `xargs` here. `find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -exec mv -t myfolder {} +` moves all JPGs and PNGs to `myfolder`, if that's what you want.

Comment: I want all png and jpg print with \0 . does the second line is equivalent to your example? (The answer say the exact opposite right?... I'm not the only one to be confused)

Comment: Neither of your commands does what you want then, but the ones I posted does. Yes, `find` can be very confusing.

Comment: You are right oguz Ismail but the actual command after xargs is more complex. Just this print0 part give me weird results. I have sometime no output or sometimes folder named as results. I don't know how it's possible...

Comment: Thanks oguz for your kind answer. :)